# How to test adding line to error log by causing rescue statement in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a this `Foo` class.

```
class Foo
  def open_url
    Net::HTTP.start("google.com") do |http|
      # Do Something
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    File.open("error.txt","a+"){|f| f.puts e.message }
  end
end
```

And I want to test by this Rspec.

```
require_relative 'foo'

describe Foo do
  describe "#open_url" do
    it "should put error log if connection fails" do
      Net::HTTP.stub(:start).and_return(Exception)
      # Check if a line to error.txt is added.
    end
  end
end
```

How can I check if a line is inserted to `error.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the file you are actually writing

```
describe Foo do
  describe "#open_url" do
    it "should put error log if connection fails" do
      Net::HTTP.stub(:start).and_raise
      Foo.open_url
      file = File.open("error.txt", "r")
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

An alternative would be to check that the file is opened: something along the lines of this

```
File.should_receive(:open).with("error.txt", "a+", {|f| f.puts e.message })
```